# Citing example from same book- different pages

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite different examples from different pages of the same book. How can I do it. How can I cite example from same book that are in different pages?
For example.

I need the citation in following form 
[image]

[image]

```
@article{10.2307/4178405,
 ISSN = {00243892, 15309150},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4178405},
 author = {K. P. Mohanan},
 journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
 number = {4},
 pages = {575-602},
 publisher = {The MIT Press},
 title = {Lexical Phonology of the Consonant System in Malayalam},
 volume = {15},
 year = {1986b}
}
```

**Update**

**The answer gives me following.**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Such things are typically added using the optional argument of the citation command. You don't say anything about your setup, here is an example with `natbib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{mohanan1986b,
 ISSN = {00243892, 15309150},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4178405},
 author = {K. P. Mohanan},
 journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
 number = {4},
 publisher = {The MIT Press},
 title = {Lexical {P}honology of the {C}onsonant {S}ystem in {M}alayalam},
 volume = {15},
 year = {1986b}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers,notesep={: }}
\begin{document}

\cite[86--88]{mohanan1986b} or \cite[186--198]{mohanan1986b}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that with numerical styles (such as `alpha`) you should only use `\cite`. With author-year citations, as shown in your image, you need `\citet[7-42]{citekey}` to get an output of the form *Author (year, pages)*. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{mohanan1986b,
 ISSN = {00243892, 15309150},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4178405},
 author = {K. P. Mohanan},
 journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
 number = {4},
 publisher = {The MIT Press},
 title = {Lexical {P}honology of the {C}onsonant {S}ystem in {M}alayalam},
 volume = {15},
 year = {1986b}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{round,notesep={: }}
\begin{document}

\citet[86--88]{mohanan1986b} or \citet[186--198]{mohanan1986b}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @karu No idea how to do what?

Comment: This is first time. I am seeing these kind of citations. I have normal citations using \cite. This is very different from the one that I am following

Comment: @karu Well, I cannot possibly know what you have done so far, as you don't show any code. However, there's nothing strange about them, just quite normal author-year citations. Even using no bibliography packages at all, `\cite[...]{...}` will work basically the same way (though you may get numerical citations instead of author-year).

Comment: @karu Oh, if you're referring to the `filecontents` stuff, then perhaps I should have explained that. All that environment does is write its content to the file specified in the argument, here `\jobname.bib`. `\jobname` is a macro that contains the name of the file you're compiling without extension, so if your `.tex` file is called `mainfile.tex`, then `\jobname` will be `mainfile`. Normally you will make the `.bib` file separately, so you wouldn't have the `filecontents` package and environment.

Comment: I understand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39009/discussion-between-karu-and-torbjorn-t).